# "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." Error when calling a web service with jQuery

Tags: javascript, web-services, jquery

I have created a web service which returns some data and am trying to access it using jquery but the console displays the following errors:

```
    OPTIONS http://localhost:56018/PhoneWebServices.asmx?op=GetMyChildren 405 (Method Not Allowed)
jQuery.ajaxTransport.sendjquery-1.7.1.js:8102
jQuery.extend.ajaxjquery-1.7.1.js:7580
LoginButton_onclickindex.html:26
(anonymous function)index.html:59
onclickindex.html:60
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:56018/PhoneWebServices.asmx?op=GetMyChildren. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I assumed the 405 error was due the 'Origin null is not allowed' error.
These are the steps I've taken so far:

- Created a website (work in progress) and created the web service in the website.
- I tested the web service by typing the url in my browser and it works.
- Created a mobile web app which tries to call the webservice but shows the above errors.

My Client-side (mobile app code):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


      function onDeviceReady() {

      }

      function LoginButton_onclick() {
      var email=document.getElementById("EmailBox").value;
      var pass=document.getElementById("PasswordBox").value;
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          url: "http://localhost:56018/PhoneWebServices.asmx?op=GetMyChildren",
          data: '{ "email" : "' + email + '", "password": "' + pass + '" }',
          dataType: "json",
          success: GetChildrenSuccess,
          failure: GetChildrenFailed
      });
  }

  function GetChildrenSuccess(response) {
      var children = eval('(' + response.d + ')');
      var child;
      for(child in children) {
          $('#ResultsDiv').innerHTML = "ID: "+child.ID+ " Name: "+child.Name+" Surname: "+child.Surname+" \r\n";
      }
  }

  function GetChildrenFailed(error) {
      document.getElementById('ResultsDiv').innerHTML = "Error";
  }

  </script>
```

I was thinking maybe it was because I did not publish the website or webservice with IIS-do I need to do this? Even though the url worked when typed into the browser I am not sure whether it should be the same in the client side code.

I am very new to web programming so if you know what's wrong please explain it in simple terms, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely to go away if you run the file through a local web server, and not just open the HTML-file with the browser. When you just open the file, without going through a web server, you don't get an origin domain - thus the error message that the origin is null.

Comment: So in order to solve this do I need to host my website in IIS?

Comment: @Matt Yes, IIS or some other web server of your choice.